# Position matrix horizontally in the center

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I would like to position tree in the north-center of the page, but for some reason advancing x coordinate of the `node-0` doesn't change anything. Using relative positioning to draw the `node-0` in the `current page.north` doesn't help either.

Does anyone has an idea of what might be going wrong here?

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [    
    array/.style = { 
        matrix of nodes, 
        nodes = { draw, minimum size = 7mm, anchor = center, fill = violet!30 },         
        nodes in empty cells        
    },    
    edge/.style = { -> }    
] 
    \matrix[array] (node-0) at (14, 0) { 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ };
    \matrix[array] (node-1) [below left=0.4cm and 0.4cm of node-0] { 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ };
    \matrix[array] (node-2) [below right=0.4cm and 0.4cm of node-0] { 0 & 1 & & \\ };

    \draw[edge] (node-0-1-1.south) to (node-1.north);
    \draw[edge] (node-0-1-2.south) to (node-2.north);    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the complete [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557).

Comment: Did you do `{\centering\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
array/.style = {
matrix of nodes,
nodes = { draw, minimum size = 7mm, anchor = center, fill = violet!30 },
nodes in empty cells
},
edge/.style = { -> }
]
\matrix[array] (node-0) at (14, 0) { 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ };
\matrix[array] (node-1) [below left=0.4cm and 0.4cm of node-0] { 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ };
\matrix[array] (node-2) [below right=0.4cm and 0.4cm of node-0] { 0 & 1 & & \\ };

\draw[edge] (node-0-1-1.south) to (node-1.north);
\draw[edge] (node-0-1-2.south) to (node-2.north);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```